# Refactoring multiple if conditions

Tags: java, refactoring

I have created a  method in which i have multiple if conditions. Now i want to refactor these if conditions. What would be the best design pattern/strategy to overcome multiple if conditions?

```
 if
        (
            poConfiguration.strSampleLoaderPluginClass != null
            && poConfiguration.strSampleLoaderPluginClass.equals("") == false
        )
        {
            setSampleLoaderPluginClass(poConfiguration.strSampleLoaderPluginClass);
        }

        if
        (
            poConfiguration.strPreprocessingPluginClass != null
            && poConfiguration.strPreprocessingPluginClass.equals("") == false
        )
        {
            setPreprocessingPluginClass(poConfiguration.strPreprocessingPluginClass);
        }

        if
        (
            poConfiguration.strFeatureExtractionPluginClass != null
            && poConfiguration.strFeatureExtractionPluginClass.equals("") == false
        )
        {
            setFeatureExtractionPluginClass(poConfiguration.strFeatureExtractionPluginClass);
        }

        if
        (
            poConfiguration.strClassificationPluginClass != null
            && poConfiguration.strClassificationPluginClass.equals("") == false
        )
        {
            setClassificationPluginClass(poConfiguration.strClassificationPluginClass);
        }
```

Please share your thoughts with implementations, if possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: consider some better code formatting.

Comment: I think you should take a look on the Command pattern -- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077569/core-java/java-tip-68--learn-how-to-implement-the-command-pattern-in-java.html

Comment: Start by extracting method isNotNullOrEmpty().  Then graduate to something like com.google.common.base.Strings.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be the polymorphism ([Click here for more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)), it depends from the concrete situation:

```
interface MyInterface {
    public boolean checkCondition(PoConfiguration poConfiguration);

    public void process(PoConfiguration poConfiguration);
}

public class SampleLoader implements MyInterface {
    public boolean checkCondition(PoConfiguration poConfiguration) {
       return poConfiguration.strSampleLoaderPluginClass != null
        && !poConfiguration.strSampleLoaderPluginClass.isEmpty();
    }

    public void process(PoConfiguration poConfiguration) {
        setSampleLoaderPluginClass(poConfiguration.strSampleLoaderPluginClass); 
    }
}

public class ClientAPI {
    public void caller() {
         for (MyInterface current : this.myInterfaces) {
             if (current.checkCondition(current)) {
                 current.process();
             }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following:

- Create a `Configuration` class that contains `ConfigurationItems`
- Each `ConfigurationItem` would have a name, value and a default value

As an improvement, you may want to create static values for the configuration items instead of using Strings.

**TestConfig main Class**

```
package com.example.config;

public class TestConfig {
    static TestConfig me;
    static String[][] confSettings = {{"sampleLoader","loaderDefault"}
                                     ,{"preProcessing","preProcessingDefualt"}
                                     ,{"featureExtraction","featureExtractionDefault"}
                                     ,{"classification","classificationDefault"}
                                     };

    // Object fields
    Configuration configuration;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        me = new TestConfig();
        me.doWork();



    }

    private void doWork() {
        configuration = new Configuration();
        for (int i=0; i < confSettings.length; i++) {
            configuration.addConfigurationItem(confSettings[i][0], confSettings[i][1], null);
        }

        configuration.setConfigurationItemDefault("classification", "newValue");

        System.out.println("sampleLoader = " + configuration.getConfigurationItemValue("sampleLoader"));

        System.out.println("classification = " + configuration.getConfigurationItemValue("classification"));


    }
}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
package com.example.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Configuration {
    // Class fields
    // Object fields
    HashMap<String,Integer> itemNames;

    ArrayList<ConfigurationItem> items;

    public Configuration() {
        items = new ArrayList<ConfigurationItem>();
        itemNames = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    }

    public Configuration addConfigurationItem(String name, String defaultValue, String value) {
        if (itemNames.containsKey(name)) {
            // handle duplicate configuration item
        } else {
            items.add(new ConfigurationItem(name, defaultValue, value));
            Integer loc = new Integer(items.size()-1);
            itemNames.put(name, loc);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void setConfigurationItemDefault(String name, String defaultValue) {

        int loc = getConfigurationItemIndex(name); 
        if (loc > -1) {
            items.get(loc).setDefaultValue(defaultValue);
        }
    }

    public String getConfigurationItemValue(String name) {
        int loc = getConfigurationItemIndex(name);
        if (loc > -1) {
            return items.get(loc).getValue();
        } else {
            // handle unknown parameter
            return null;
        }
    }

    private int getConfigurationItemIndex(String name) {
        if (itemNames.containsKey(name)) {
            return itemNames.get(name);
        } else {
            // handle unknown parameter
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

**ConfigurationItem Class**

```
package com.example.config;

public class ConfigurationItem {
    // Object fields
    String name;
    String value;
    String defaultValue;

    public ConfigurationItem(){};
    public ConfigurationItem(String name, String defaultValue, String value) {
        this.setName(name).setDefaultValue(defaultValue).setValue(value);
    }

    public ConfigurationItem setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
    public ConfigurationItem setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }
    public ConfigurationItem setDefaultValue(String defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        return this;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return defaultValue;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```